# VBA GetElementsByClassName gets error 5002

Tags: html, excel, vba, getelementsbyclassname

First time I'm asking a question so here we go..

I have some experience in VBA but now I've been requested to do some web scraping for what I' ve been reading and doing some research in HTML as well.. the thing is I have a problem I can't solve.

There is really no difficulties in what I need to do.. just get some elements like buttons to be clicked or input forms to be auto completed but this one is the one I can't access to:

```
<div class="dojoPopupMenu2" style="left: 31px; top: 293px; z-index: 1001;" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">
 <ul dojoattachpoint="containerNode">
  <li class="dojoMenuItem2 " dojoattachevent="onMouseOver: onHover; onMouseOut: onUnhover; onclick: _onclick; onKey:onKey;" dojoinsertionindex="0"><span tabindex="-1" class="dojoMenuItem2Label">1</span></li>
 <li class="dojoMenuItem2 " dojoattachevent="onMouseOver: onHover; onMouseOut: onUnhover; onclick: _onclick; onKey:onKey;" dojoinsertionindex="1"><span tabindex="-1" class="dojoMenuItem2Label">2</span></li>
 <li class="dojoMenuItem2 " dojoattachevent="onMouseOver: onHover; onMouseOut: onUnhover; onclick: _onclick; onKey:onKey;" dojoinsertionindex="2"><span tabindex="-1" class="dojoMenuItem2Label">3</span></li>
 <li class="dojoMenuItem2" dojoattachevent="onMouseOver: onHover; onMouseOut: onUnhover; onclick: _onclick; onKey:onKey;" dojoinsertionindex="3"><span tabindex="-1" class="dojoMenuItem2Label">4</span></li>
 <li class="dojoMenuItem2" dojoattachevent="onMouseOver: onHover; onMouseOut: onUnhover; onclick: _onclick; onKey:onKey;" dojoinsertionindex=`enter code here`"4"><span tabindex="-1" class="dojoMenuItem2Label">5</span>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There is a previous button called "Add Items" that when it's clicked you get a dropdown list with numbers 1 to 5 (code above) and That's what I need to select.. these numbers depending on some simple conditionals

I have tried these options but none seem to work

```
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieEl As HTMLDivElement
Dim ieEls As HTMLObjectElement
Dim direccion As String
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ieApp
For Each element In .document.getElementsByTagName("div") 'Tried with the tag "li" as well
    if element.classname = "dojoMenuItem2" Then
        'set a variable with the number 1 to 5 from the list (depending on other condition)
    end if
Next
End With


'also tried this
Dim additems as HTMLDivElement
Set additems = ieDoc.GetElementsByClassName("dojoMenuItem2")(0)
'this gets Automate error

'also tried this
Dim additems as HTMLDivElement
Set additems = ieDoc.GetElementsByClassName("dojoPopupMenu2")(0)
'this gets Automate error
```

Nothing seems to work so I don't know what I'm not seeing.

Thanks!

Comment: (FYI) In general, you should avoid `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByClassName()`, and `getElementsByName()` because they all have a high performance impact as they return "live" node lists. Instead, use the more modern `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()`, which return static node lists.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to determine exactly what line the error occurs on?

Comment: Is there an URL you can share?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm going to read more about these methods and see if I can find a way around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to apply a CSS attribute selector?

```
ieApp.document.querySelectorAll("[dojoinsertionindex]")
```

The attribute selector `[dojoinsertionindex]` will return all elements with attribute `[dojoinsertionindex]`.

This returns a `nodeList` you can index into.

Or loop the length of:

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
Set aNodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("[dojoinsertionindex]")  
For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length-1
    Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i).innerText '< === as check
Next i
```

Click a partic index (starts at 0 for 1)

```
aNodeList.item(0).Click
```

---

**CSS selector on your HTML sample:**

[image: query]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've tried this and now there's no error but i'm getting a null value.. so aNodeList length is zero. Unfortunately the URL requires login to access so I can't share it..

Comment: Is this inside any kind of form/frame/iframe tags by the way?

Comment: Hey QHarr! I was few days withouth access to my computer.
I took this from where we left it and could find a solution!

I got the the element called "Add items" and once that's clicks and the options 1,2,3,4,5 are displayed, with your piece of code I could easily get the number i needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I need to learn more about HTML :)